# Digital signing using iText without description (just image)

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I'm tryng to sign digitally a pdf using iText and I achieved successfully helped by [this example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=222).

What I would like to do is to display just the sign of the signer and not the text saying

> DIGITALLY SIGNED BY XXXX ON DATE XXXX

If I set up the image with the signature's one, the image is displayed but I can't remove those unuseful for me descriptions (that are readable in the signature propreties, no need to be displayed on the main view of the pdf).

```
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper .getSignatureAppearance();
appearance.setImage(Image.getInstance(IMAGE));
appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(0, 672, 200, 792), 1, "first");
```

Those are the signature appearances that are shown on the example and there is (apparently) nothing writing the descriptions I mentioned.

Is it possible to remove them from the signature appearances?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this line

```
appearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC);
```

after this

```
appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(0, 672, 200, 792), 1, "first");
```

this will display image without this description `DIGITALLY SIGNED BY XXXX ON DATE XXXX`

Answer (score 5):

It worked after adding the line:

```
appearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC);
```

But only after I also added the line:

```
appearance.setSignatureGraphic(Image.getInstance(IMAGE));
```

and removed:

```
appearance.setImage(Image.getInstance(IMAGE));
```

(You have to set a render image to the graphic appearance if you use GRAPHIC rendering mode)

Not sure if is needed to edit your answear or not.

Comment: 1+ for appearance.setImage(Image.getInstance(Image));
:)